# Create html with links to different folder in Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, html, promoted-links, links, html-form-web-part

I saw this html part that had different links to different sites or folder inside SharePoint.

Is it possible to create on that would consist of  links to different folder inside  document libary

The idea is when the user goes inside the site, they see this big window that a Team Related background picture and around 3 columns with different links that looks like buttons to different document in the document library.

Comment: That is certainly possible. What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Ed1995,
You can use the quick link web part in modern experiences. Insert that web part to a modern page, click add link, then you can select desired folders directly through UI and that's it. 
[image]
[image]

[image]